# Good example of a unit-tested Django project?

Tags: django, unit-testing

I'm looking for a good large-sized Django project that uses good test practices. I've read a lot of material and tutorials, but I find that they tend to be rather simple. As in, the examples test relatively simple things but don't always go into much detail about how the test suite will grow or how more complicated things get tested.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

How about Django itself?

If you're looking for a Django app - there's always flatpages, which is part of `contrib`. You'll find the tests for it [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/flatpages/tests).

Comment: Hey that's a really good idea! I suppose the django-admin test suite is probably a good place to look too.

Comment: @TonyArkles - that was my first thought too - but I couldn't find one. I was probably looking in the wrong place.